# Show name of last command in echo area

Tags: emacs

I executed `C-x M-k` to kill a paragraph in Emacs. The echo area showed `C-x M-k`, as expected.

However, is it possible to (also) show the **name** of the last command just executed, for reference? This would be useful for learning purposes, as well as confirming that the command executed was the command intended.

Comment: Just curious, do you know about the `describe-key` function?  For example, `M-x describe-key` `C-x C-f` opens the `find-file` info page (assuming a default `C-f` key binding).

Comment: Yes, I know about `C-h k` :)

Comment: Not sure if it is of interest, but `C-x ESC ESC` shows the last command (for *redo*, `C-g` to abort)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't necessarily a good idea, but you can advise `call-interactively` to do what you say:

```
(defadvice call-interactively (after show-last-command activate)
  "Shows the interactive command that was just run in the message area."
  (unless (eq major-mode 'minibuffer-inactive-mode)
    (message "Ran %s" (ad-get-arg 0))))
```

To turn this off, run `(ad-unadvise 'call-interactively)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this via the hook [`'post-command-hook`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Command-Overview.html#Command-Overview).  You'll just want to add to the list of filtered commands to avoid a bunch of annoying messages.

```
(defvar filtered-commands '(self-insert-command previous-line next-line 
                            forward-char backward-char execute-extended-command))

(defun my-post-command-function ()
  (when (and (= 0 (recursion-depth)) (not (memq this-command filtered-commands)))
(message (format "command was %s" this-command))))

(add-hook 'post-command-hook 'my-post-command-function)
```

Obviously, add to the variable `filtered-commands` as you see fit.  You might also want to tweak the code to accept regular expressions to reduce the number of commands you need to list.  That is left as an exercise to the user.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this can be done. Remember that any echoing will be (soon) replaced by any messages that the function itself echoes in message area.

You might be able to use `C-h k` (`describe-key`) and `C-h l` (`view-lossage`); the latter shows the last 300 keystrokes.

Comment: I thought of echoing out the variable `last-command`, but your point about this potentially being replaced by other messages is noted.

Comment: `real-last-command` is similar but never altered by Lisp code.

Comment: I think that's C-h k (C-x k is kill-buffer for me)

Answer (score 0):

Based on reading in the documentation, this does not seem possible in a non-hackish way. However, you may be able to use the hook `echo-area-clear-hook` to look back at what was in the echo area, if it looks like a keystroke look it up with `describe-key`, and then log the name of the function you get from that to the echo area.